# In vim, is there a way to rebind "*" to highlight the current word, without advancing to the next?

Tags: vim, editor, key-bindings

I often use * to highlight all instances of the current word, and the fact that it advances to the next word is pretty annoying. I'd like to disable this behavior, knowing that I can always use "n" if I actually need to advance.

Any insight?

EDIT: I should add that I'd like to avoid a screen redraw at all costs as it is visually distracting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
nnoremap * :let @/ = "\\<<C-R><C-W>\\>"<CR>
```

(Assumes you have `'hlsearch'` on).  This just changes the current search pattern to the word under the cursor (surrounded by `\<` and `\>` to match word boundaries).  If you have `hlsearch` enabled, it will highlight the word.  `n` and `N` will then work as normal.

See:

```
:help :let-@
:help quote/
:help c_CTRL-R_CTRL-W
```

Comment: Works as advertised. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `let @/ = '\<'.expand('<cword>').'\>'<cr>` works well too.

Comment: @Luc Hermitte : is it any better?

Comment: @Al : it doesn't seem to work if you haven't made a search before you use it the first time. Would you have a workaround? I try to get the keybindings I use as perfect as possible so I can forget about them :)

Comment: @AI, @Luc Hermitte You all again forget about escaping: `let @/='\V\<LT>'.escape(expand('<cword>'), '\').'\>'<CR>` (uses very no-magic).

Comment: @ZyX, I always forget about escaping. ^^'

Comment: @static_rtti. I prefer the `expand()` form as I found it easier to maintain. We don't have to play with double-quotes instead of single-quotes and thus ask ourselves which characters must be doubled.

Comment: @Luc Hermitte It works in single quotes as well, I do not know why @AI used double one. There is still another concern: I can't imagine an easy way to escape values inserted by `<C-r><C-w>`.

Answer (score 2):

Try [this Vim Tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1572). I find it very useful. The most interesting is that you can have more matches and every one in different color.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot give an exact answer, but [this Vim Tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Auto_highlight_current_word_when_idle) tells you what you have to add to your `.vimrc` to simply highlight the word under the cursor when Vim is in idle state.

Works without any key-remapping...

Comment: I've seen this tip, but I don't want to highlight it automatically, I'd find that very distracting. Now if someone knows how to adapt it to what I want to do...

Comment: @static_rtti: well, you could toggle the script activity by typing `z/`. Did you see that? If you want the highlighting, type `z/`, if you don't need it anymore, type `z/` again...

Answer (score 1):

You can remap it to return:

```
nnoremap * '*N'
```

(but this redraws the screen)

Comment: I thought about that, but I really want to avoid the screen redraw...

Comment: Hm, why do you have `<expr>` here? It is for more complex cases, `nnoremap * *N` gives the same result.

Comment: @static_rtti It should not redraw anything if `lazyredraw` is set (but it stil may move window position of cursor line and may open folds).

Comment: @ZyX: Too exited learning (from you btw) a new trick I guess :)